# Show diff of two SQLite databases ignoring rowid

Tags: sqlite

First I create a database with one table which holds two records:

```
C:\Software\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000>sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.36.0 2021-06-18 18:36:39
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open test.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE people(first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY([first_name], [last_name]));
sqlite> INSERT INTO people(first_name, last_name) VALUES ("John", "Doe");
sqlite> INSERT INTO people(first_name, last_name) VALUES ("Jane", "Doe");
sqlite> .quit
```

Then I copied the database and checked that they were equal:

```
C:\Software\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000>copy test.db test2.db
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Software\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000>sqldiff.exe test.db test2.db

C:\Software\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000>
```

Then I removed the first record and added the record again:

```
C:\Software\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000>sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.36.0 2021-06-18 18:36:39
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open test2.db
sqlite> DELETE FROM people WHERE first_name = 'John' AND last_name = 'Doe';
sqlite> INSERT INTO people(first_name, last_name) VALUES ("John", "Doe");
sqlite> .quit
```

After that I compared the two databases again:

```
C:\Software\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000>sqldiff.exe test.db test2.db
DELETE FROM people WHERE rowid=1;
INSERT INTO people(rowid,first_name,last_name) VALUES(3,'John','Doe');

C:\Software\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000>
```

I understand the output, since the rowid of the record 'John' 'Doe' is different.

However, I don't care about the rowid in my usecase.

How can I see a diff of two databases/tables that are considered equal as long as the data that can be queried are equal?

In other words two records should be considered equal as long as all values except the rowid are the same...

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to use thirdpary tools, I can suggest [KS DB Merge for SQLite](https://ksdbmerge.tools/sqlite-diff-merge-overview.html). It compares data by primary key, not by rowid. Free version available, here is the screenshot from Free version with these DBs:
[image]
Any changes would be highlighted. It has some limitations on number of columns in table and PK, but two-column keys are supported.
I am the author of that tool.

Answer (score 0):

from `sqldiff` documentation [link](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html):

> The --primarykey flag changes the pairing algorithm slightly so that the schema-declared PRIMARY KEY is always used for pairing, even on tables that have a rowid. This is often a better choice for finding differences, however it can lead to missed differences in the case of rows that have one or more PRIMARY KEY columns set to NULL.

you can do this with:  `sqldiff.exe --primarykey db1.db db2.db`